# Transform response of fastify-static served files

Tags: node.js, server, fastify

I'm using fastify's fastify-static plugin, and need to transform files that it is serving.  For example, I'd like to replace "this-link" with "that-link".  I've tried various fastify.addHook() events listed here, https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Hooks/, and the sensible one to me is the "onSend" where they demonstrate [string].replace(), but all have failed.  For the onSend handler, the payload is not a mutable string, but instead it appears to be a PassThrough readable stream.  With that in mind, I tried inspecting the data with `payload.on('data', (chunk) => {...})`.  That was insightful. I could see the file text, but I'm treading a bit deep into streams and fastify plugins and not sure how to proceed.

1. Is there a simple way to transform responses before they are sent when using fastify-static? (Why are the documented addHook()'s failing?)
2. Assuming I properly interpreted the payload as a readable stream, how can I transform that before fastify-static sends it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An endpoint can send strings, buffer or streams.

So the `onSend` hook will receive one of those data type.

As example:

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')()
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

fastify.addHook('onSend', async (request, reply, payload) => {
  console.log(`Payload is a ${payload}`);
  return typeof payload
})

fastify.get('/string', (req, reply) => { reply.send('a string') })
fastify.get('/buffer', (req, reply) => { reply.send(Buffer.from('a buffer')) })
fastify.get('/stream', (req, reply) => { reply.send(fs.createReadStream(__filename)) })


fastify.inject('/string', (_, res) => console.log(res.payload))
fastify.inject('/buffer', (_, res) => console.log(res.payload))
fastify.inject('/stream', (_, res) => console.log(res.payload))
```

`fastify-static` sends files as a stream, so you would need to implement a Transform stream.
Here a quick and dirty example assuming a `static/hello` file exists with content:

> Hello %name

```js
const { Transform } = require('stream')
const fastify = require('fastify')()
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const transformation = new Transform({
  writableObjectMode: false,
  transform(chunk, encoding, done) {
    const str = chunk.toString()
    this.push(str.replace('%name', 'foo bar'))
    done()
  }
})

fastify.addHook('onSend', async (request, reply, payload) => {
  if (typeof payload.pipe === 'function') {
    // check if it is a stream
    return payload.pipe(transformation)
  }
  return payload
})

fastify.register(require('fastify-static'), {
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
  prefix: '/static/',
})

fastify.inject('/static/hello', (_, res) => console.log(res.payload))
```

As a suggestion, I would use a templating system from the [point-of-view](https://github.com/fastify/point-of-view) plugins, since it supports these kinds of features out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer and tips for templating system!  I may switch to templating if I can't solve things this way.  I'm already using handlebars on static preprocessed renders.  Right now I'm trying to transform those results on the fly for dev and test reasons.  Your code set me off in the right direction for a deeper understanding of streams. Unfortunately I'm stuck on two issues.  The first is an error "MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected.", which seems like an easy fix, but the second is that pipe'ing to transform severely slows fastify.